# Ms Access 2007 ComboBox

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I am using Access for a quick and dirty (ADP) interface for an SQL (Express 2012) database so data entry can begin before the MVC web app interface is complete.

There is one field I want to be varchar, I would like this field to either allow the user to type in a value or select from a distinct list of values previously used in that field.

I have that part down, but the problem is when it happens, I have to refresh the recordset to see the new item in the list, so if they choose add a new record, then the last item added is not visible in the list.

So I can get the distinct list, populate the box, allow for new entry, and save that to the DB, do I have to write a code behind to repopulate the recordset, do I need to write a code behind to maintain the list paralleled to the recordset, or is there just a property I am missing?

Thanks

(Added screen showing event)[image]

Comment: I am fairly certain you will have to requery the combobox.

Comment: In what event? I have tried to requery the form on change of the combo, and on save, but it seems to then bring me back to the first record every time rather than where I was.

Comment: Don't requery the form, just requery the combo: Me.MyCombo.Requery. The best bet is probably the current event or the after update event for the combo.

Comment: Tried that 

Private Sub Combo4_AfterUpdate()
Me.Controls("Combo4").Requery
End Sub

After update, on progressing to next record the last item entered is not in the list even though the value is retained, closing and reopening form it is there.

Comment: Put your `Me.Controls("Combo4").Requery` in the form's after insert and after update events.  Does that give you what you want?

Comment: The current event works and would be good if more than one person is doing data entry. It will also work if people are editing the table as well as entering data, whereas after insert will only work for additions.

Comment: I do not have an after insert, or a current event?

Comment: Switch the form to Design View.  Open it's property sheet (Alt+Enter).  Select "Form" in the "Selection type" dropdown on the property sheet.  Select the "Event" tab.  Click in the box next to your target event, then click the "..." symbol to create a procedure stub for that event.

Comment: Added screen shot of the event tab.

Comment: That screen shot shows the property sheet for Combo4.  I suggested Form  (not Combo4) as the Selection Type.

Comment: Ahhh, my bad, I see those events now.
Looks like current did the trick, thank you.

Comment: When the after update event of a combo fires, the control value has changed, but the current record has not been saved.  So requery of the combo's row source at that point will not pick up the new value you just added.

Comment: So how do I mark a comment as answer?

Comment: Using the form's current event for this means you will requery `SELECT  DISTINCT ...` for every row you visit in the form.  My instinct was to avoid that ... and only requery when new values may have been added ... however you want "quick & dirty", so maybe current is fine.

Comment: You can't mark a comment as an answer.  Suggest you add your own answer which describes the solution which worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't requery the form, just requery the combo. The best bet is probably the current event which will work if more than one person is doing data entry. It will also work if people are editing the table as well as entering data. Events that only fire when a record is added will not pick up changes to the combo contents.

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
   Me.MyCombo.Requery
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, using the on current event on the form and the after update solved the problem.

Clicking the form section detail selected the detail sections property page not the form. Selecting the form from the drop down on the property page displayed the events I was suggested to use.

Many thanks to those contributing.

As the first suggestion of this was from Remau, with assist in locating that event from hansup, I will mark remau's post as answer. Thank you to both.